# Is there any way how to print "changing" variable in Python tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

I've got some variable in while loop:

```
import pyautogui as py

while True:
   x, y = py.position()
```

Is there any way how to print these variables in tkinter window - in for example label, even when it is while loop? Or is there any way how to print "changing" variable in tkinter label?

Comment: read how to use `after` method to create "loops" in `tkinter`

Comment: in tkinter you should use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to execute function periodically. And then it get position and replace text in `Label` - `label["text"] = some_text`. Eventually `Label` may use `tkinter.StringVar()` as textvariable` and then `after` may run code which change value in `StringVar` and it will automatically change text in `Label`. But both function need to run after for this.

Comment: if `x,y` is mouse position then in `tkinter` you can `bind()` function to event `mouse move` to execute function when mouse changes position. If `x,y` is window position then you may try to `bind()` function to event `configure` to run function when window change size and position.

Comment: if you really have to run it with `while`-loop then you may need `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to redraw widgets in window after changing text in label.

Comment: do you want position on `screen`/`desktop` or on `tkinter.Canvas`? `tkinter` may use own methods to get position on `Canvas`

Answer (score 0):

In `tkinter` you should rather use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while`-loop because `while`-loop will block `mainloop` and `tkinter` will freeze. Using `after` it will send information to `mainloop` and it will run it after `milliseconds` and it will have also time to get mouse/key events from system, send them to widgets and update/redraw all widgets in window so it will not freeze.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as py

# --- functions ---

def update_label():
    x, y = py.position()
    label['text'] = f'{x}, {y}' 
    root.after(25, update_label)  # run again after 25ms
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)  # with empty text
label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

#update_label()  # run first time at once
root.after(25, update_label)  # run first time after 25ms

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you really have to use `while`-loop then you will have to use `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to update widgets in window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as py

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)  # with empty text
label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

while True:
    x, y = py.position()
    label['text'] = f'{x}, {y}'
    root.update()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved the problem, really appreciate your help:)